# Fixed gradient background color?

Tags: javascript, background, three.js, gradient, fixed

How to make a fixed gradient background? I have tried a few `CSS` and `HTML` code like this:

```
.mygradienttop {
  background-color: #C5C2C2;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#651212), to(#C5C2C2), color-stop(.5,#462020));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #651212 0%, #462020 50%, #C5C2C2 100%);
}
```

But it's not working. I'm using three.js `r63`.

Comment: Which part is not working?  Which browser(s)?

Comment: Every browse, no error in debug, the background still black, not gradient.

Comment: I realized when i change my three.js viewport to 800x600, i see the gradient background in the back, so how to make gradient background in three.js?

Comment: aww, i fixed it, just because my alpha is 0, when i change to 1, work perfectly.

Comment: Please post an answer and accept your own answer. Provide all the relevant code so the problem and solution are clear.